# C++ My string Has No Effect

Tags: c++, string, effect

I'm new to programming, this is probably going to be a stupid question but I can't get this simple code to work on Eclipse. I'm using C++.

```
int main() {


   string fruits[] = {"Apple", "Melon", "Banana". "Orange", "Pineapple"};

   cout << "Fruit I want to eat : " << fruit[3] << endl;


   return 0;
}
```

I keep getting `( Statement has no effect 'string')` and other stuff errors, help?

Comment: Adding to moffeltje answer, also its better to use .at instead of operator[]

Answer (score 7):

You have a typo: you create a string array called `fruits` and you are using the name `fruit` in your `cout`.

I also see a `.` (dot) in your array, right after `"Banana"`.